# missing rows in output with write.table in R script, but not RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, write.table

I am trying to write a data frame from R to a plain text file. When I develop my script in RStudio and use write.table() to export the data I get the expected number of rows, but when I run my script from the command line I get 360 fewer rows... This is despite giving the same inputs to commandArgs when calling the script from the command line or walking through it in RStudio. Very puzzling...

The write.table call is as follows:

```
write.table(SSID_to_print, file = SSID_output_file, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

My data frame is too large to include, but here's the summary of it:

> summary(SSID_to_print)
>         V1                 V2
>    Length:1746        Length:1746
>    Class :character   Class :character
>    Mode  :character   Mode  :character

Any help would be greatly appreciated!